# Material tab is not responsive

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material-tab

I have Material tab on left hand side of split area.
[image]

When I move splitter to reduce width of tab group, active link mark stays and does not respond to the updated width.

[image]

How can I make responsive tabs? I created on [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf1ejk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

remove
flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 5.5px);

and assign 100% width to all the parent containers